# Cannot iterate Hashmap C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, iteration

I am trying to write a very easy and banal program in which the user is prompt to enter the name of three animals and three dimensions (height, weight and age). I want to store this as a Hashmap of the sort {"animal":{height, weight, age}}.

When I try to iterate over the key values (animal name), it works, but the problem is when it comes to iterate over the key. The problem is driving me crazy since I don't understand concepts such as overload for iterator and so on, which I have seen in other post as a way I have to modify my code so it can iterate over the second value for every key in my hashmap.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <list>


using namespace std;


int main(){


   map <string, list<float>> measurements;

    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
       string name;
       float height, weight, age;
       cout << "Please enter the animals' name: " << i << endl;
       cin >> name;
       cout << "Enter the height, weight, age" << endl;
       cin >> height >> weight >> age;
       measurements[name] = {height, weight, age};
    } 
    for (auto x: measurements) {
        cout << x.first << endl;

        cout << x.second << endl;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never insert anything in `measurements`, or have any lists to get iterators of to insert into it (assuming you fix it to use the right type). Nor does anything in that involve hash tables...

Comment: there is no `grades` declared, is this a typo during modifiying the code to post it here? Please make sure the code and the behaviour you describe are in sync. I cannot get the code to compile (and I am a bit puzzled by the error) https://wandbox.org/permlink/NYKUxWX02ocEUtxF

Comment: the error is because `list::iterator<float>` makes no sense. Please post real code. Or at least include the error message in the question, currently it is not clear what problem you are trying to fix

Comment: still does not compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1EPpmvQRUrguaXst

Comment: `x.second` is a `list`. Do you know how to print each element of a `list` ? Is that the problem?

Comment: Not at all, that is the problem, I just come from the python world, and I thought that only by putting the value with the cout statement in C++ the complete list with the 3 values per key will be displayed.

Comment: see answer. Please next time try to be more clear. You should include the error message in the question and better make sure (eg in an online compiler) that the code you post really does what you claim. If you say "it works" but the code has several compiler errors then this looks as if the code you posted is different from the one you are actually trying to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no output operator (`operator<<`) for a `std::list`, just as there is no output operator for a `std::map`. In the same way you iterate the map you can iterate the list:

```
for (const auto& x: measurements) {
    std::cout << x.first << "\n";
    for (const auto& y : x.second) {
        std::cout << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

I replaced `auto` with `const auto&` because in case of `auto` alone the type gets deduced to be the value type and then `x` is a copy of the elements in the map. This copy can be avoided by using `const auto&`, then `x` is a (const) reference to the elements in the map.